# How to debug a MapReduce task on the terminal?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Is there a simple way to simulate a MapReduce job using the terminal? I wonder if there is an easy way to debug my code while writing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm used to Hadoop streaming with Python, but I believe this solution can be replicated for other languages as well. So, here it goes my solution:

`cat input_folder/* | python map.py | sort | python reduce.py`

It's also valid to mention that you can see the values your reducer receives as input, by simply running:

`cat input_folder/* | python map.py | sort`

Comment: Generally, this is a good option to test the algorithmic feature of MapReduce job. This does not hold true when you want to test other features like compression technique, number of mappers, s3 writes,etc.